# Palindrom recursion: Simplify conditional ternary expression

Tags: c#, recursion, palindrome, conditional-operator, simplify

I needed to implement a recursive method that checks whether an input is a palindrome or not. I was able to do this in one line and it works, but I'm not sure about how readable this is. I also keep getting a message "**Simplify conditional ternary expression**" but I'm not sure how
 this is my code:

```
private static bool checkIfPalindrome(string i_InputToCheck, int i_StartIndex, int i_EndIndex)
    {
        return (i_StartIndex >= i_EndIndex) ? true : checkIfPalindrome(i_InputToCheck, i_StartIndex + 1, i_EndIndex - 1) && (i_InputToCheck[i_StartIndex] == i_InputToCheck[i_EndIndex]);
    }
```

Comment: We are only allowed to use 1 return statement

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need help with ternary expression simplification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how readable this is

First off, naming convention: Get rid of unnecessary/uninformative parts of identifiers. For example, parameters do *not* need to start with `i_` (presumably to denote “input”?). There’s no information conveyed here, and it adds noise. This has a *huge* impact on readability.

The logic itself can also be decluttered. The warning you’re getting gives you a hint that the condition can be simplified — this is always the case when your conditionals contain boolean literals.

More than anything, however, readability would benefit from breaking the expression up over multiple lines.

I would also swap the two secondary conditions, so that you *first* test the current characters, and *then* recurse further (only if the two currently tested characters are equal!):

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string input, int start, int end) {
    return (start >= end) ||
        input[start] == input[end] &&
        IsPalindrome(input, start + 1, end - 1);
}
```

This code relies on the correct precedence of `&&` over `||`. Some peope prefer making this operator precedence explicit by using more parentheses:

```
private static bool IsPalindrome(string input, int start, int end) {
    return (start >= end) ||
        (
            input[start] == input[end] &&
            IsPalindrome(input, start + 1, end - 1)
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! The naming conventions are a must in my course, to be able to better read long code.

Answer (score 1):

```
return i_StartIndex >= i_EndIndex || checkIfPalindrome(i_InputToCheck, i_StartIndex + 1, i_EndIndex - 1) && i_InputToCheck[i_StartIndex] == i_InputToCheck[i_EndIndex];
```

The simplification being prompted is because you're testing a boolean expression and then unnecessarily checking and returning it...

`if (expression == true)` is equivalent to `if (expression)` and

`return expression ? true : false` to `return expression`.

It is certainly not easy on the eye but I assume this is for a school exercise?